# Does compiler make a difference between static and dynamic libraries (unix, C++,Qt creator)?

Tags: c++, qt, shared-libraries, static-libraries, cpprest-sdk

this is my first post on stack overflow!

I have a problem I am using ***Qt creator*** and my program uses **libcpprest** and I currently have (dynamic) one on my system.

i checked that with `ldconfig -p | grep libcpprest` and the output is

```
libcpprest.so.2.10 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so.2.10
libcpprest.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcpprest.so
```

but when compiling my compiler cant link to library

```
error: cannot find -lcpprest
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

But when i put (static) **libcpprest.a** in *use/Lib/x86_64* directory it finds the lib but generates a bunch of other problems that i believe is due to incompatible versions of **libcpprest** used when compiling other libraries that my program uses.

But i will include those here as well

```
error: ./use/Lib/x86_64/libcpprest.a(json.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
use/Lib/x86_64/libcpprest.a(json_parsing.cpp.o): error: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `_ZNSbIwSt11char_traitsIwESaIwEE4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE@@GLIBCXX_3.4' can not be used when making a PIE object; recompile with -fPIC
error: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my question is does linker makes a difference between static and dynamic libraries?

And what causes linker to not link dynamic lib but works fine with static one?

EDIT:
Adding my .pro file

```
QT -= gui
CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0


    #-O2
DEFINES +=  __LINUX__

DESTDIR = ../output/

__i386__ { DESTDIR = ./output_i386}
__arm7__ { DESTDIR = ./output_arm7}
__arm6__ { DESTDIR = ./output_arm6}
__x86_64__ { DESTDIR = ./output_x86_64}
INCLUDEPATH +=  \
            ./use/Include \
            ./..\
SOURCES += \
    Modules/SkupModuleASI.cpp \
    Modules/SkupModuleCID.cpp \
    Modules/SkupModuleOPR.cpp \
    Modules/SkupModuleREF_DMN.cpp \
    Modules/SkupModuleRES.cpp \
    Modules/SkupModuleTAR.cpp \
    Modules/SkupModuleTRS.cpp \
    Modules/SkupModuleTSD.cpp \
    SkupDataProvider.cpp \ 
    SkupImport.cpp \
    main.cpp

__i386__   { LIBS += -L./use/Lib/i386 }
__arm7__   { LIBS += -L./use/Lib/arm7 }
__arm6__   { LIBS += -L./use/Lib/arm6 }
__x86_64__ { LIBS += -L./use/Lib/x86_64 }


LIBS += \
    -Wl,-Bstatic \
    -lSkupWSImport\
    -lcpprest \
    -lboost_system \
    -lboost_thread \
    -Wl,-Bdynamic \
    -lemlog \
    -lcurl \
    -lssl \
    -lCore \
    -lsqlite3\
    -lmysqlcppconn\
    -lcrypto \

HEADERS += \
    Modules/SkupModuleASI.h \
    Modules/SkupModuleCID.h \
    Modules/SkupModuleOPR.h \
    Modules/SkupModuleREF_DMN.h \
    Modules/SkupModuleRES.h \
    Modules/SkupModuleTAR.h \
    Modules/SkupModuleTRS.h \
    Modules/SkupModuleTSD.h \
    SkupDataProvider.h \
    SkupImport.h \

DISTFILES += \
    data/config.xml \
    data/settings.txt
```

Comment: Are you building for a 32-bit target? What does your project (`.pro`) file look like? Please [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: Only your *linker* knows about libraries. Your compiler don't. On Linux, read [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf)

Comment: I am building for __x86_64__